# Userform in excel sheet-Can it be made an add in

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform that is used to generate reports.
In case i have to share the userform with someone i share the entire excel sheet.
Is it possible to make the existing user form as an Add-in.so that,once installed it can be accessible through any excel sheet that is opened and not just that particular excel sheet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, but, you need to do a bit of preparation.

Ensure your addin has a Project name that differs from the name of your workbook. For example, if your user's workbook's Project is called `VBAProject`, then your add-in's project name must be (and should be named something more appropriate anyway) as something like `MyAddin`.

So, you have:

- `Book1.xlsm` (Project name = `VBAProject`), and
- `MyAddin.xlam` (Project name `MyAddin`)

Steps:

1. Within Book1/VBAProject, add a reference (Tools..References) to `MyAddin`.
2. Within MyAddin, create your UserForm (`MyUserForm`)
3. For early-binding, we need to make the form instancing `PublicNotCreatable`, but the VBE UI doesn't offer that property for forms, so we need to export the form to a file folder, then edit the `MyUserForm.frm` file, changing the `Attribute VB_Exposed` attribute to `True` (by default it's False). That is, in a text editor, edit the exported file named `MyUserForm.frm` and adjust the existing line as follows:

   ```
   Attribute VB_Exposed = True
   ```
4. Save the file changes, (delete the original form in MyAddin) and then Import the MyUserForm.frm into the project. The new user form will have `PublicNotCreatable` instancing.
5. Add a public factory function to `MyAddin`, that will create a new instance of the form, and return it to any VBA that calls it:

   ```
   Public Function GetUserForm() As MyUserForm
     Set GetUserForm = New MyUserForm
   End Function
   ```
6. In `Book1.xlsm`, you can now write code like the following, along with **full early-binding support**.

   ```
   Public Sub test()

     Dim frm As MyAddin.MyUserForm
     Set frm = MyAddin.GetUserForm()
     frm.Show        
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can share the userform.

Right click on the userform and Export it.

And you can add the form by Importing it.

Thanks