# Showing an xlam userform in an xlsm

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I have a form in an xlam.  I would like the form to be usable in an xlsm.

With the help of ThunderFrame's link, I think I am close, but have no idea where to go from here.

I followed the steps in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231935/userform-in-excel-sheet-can-it-be-made-an-add-in](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), but get error "Compiler error: Method or data member not found" when I add code to a toggle button.  I tried adding the GetUserForm function in the xlam's form code, which failed, then in an xlsm's module, which failed.  Here is my code:

```
Public Function GetUserForm() As frmQuickQuote
  Set GetUserForm = New frmQuickQuote
End Function
```

Here is my toggle button code:

```
Private Sub tglQQ_Click()
    Dim frm As PRI_Comp_Life.frmQuickQuote
    
    If tglQQ Then
        tglQQ.BackColor = lngPressed
        Set frm = PRI_Comp_Life.GetUserForm()
        frm.Show
    Else
        tglQQ.BackColor = lngUnPressed
        Unload frmQuickQuote
    End If
End Sub
```

I was expecting the form to load when I pressed the toggle button tglQQ, and unload when I pressed it again.  Thanks.

EDIT: form now showing, but getting an error "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed" when the form loads.  Form code:

```vb
Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
    Dim MyLoop As Integer
    
    'Set defaults
    Me.cboRepLevel = Range("rngDefaultContract") 'errors here
    With Me.cboAge
        For MyLoop = 18 To 70
            .AddItem MyLoop
        Next MyLoop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean `Unload frm` and not `Unload frmQuickQuote` ?  And shouldn't frm be a Global or Static variable?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

In the `ThisWorkbook` module of the add-in

```vb
Public Function GetForm() As Object
    Dim frm As frmTest
    Set frm = New frmTest  'a form in the add-in
    Set GetForm = frm
End Function
```

Button code:

```vb
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    Dim addin As Object
    Static frm As Object
    
    If ToggleButton1.Value Then
        Set addin = Workbooks("test.xlam")
        Set frm = addin.getform()
        frm.Show vbModeless
    Else
        Unload frm
    End If
End Sub
```

Note it's all very late-bound.

Comment: TIm, your answer got me to the point of the form loading!  When it does the form in the xlam references a range, but I get a run-time error 104: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.  I don't know if this is a separate question, but from my view, the form does not properly load.  Any help is much appreciated, as I am not an expert programmer.

Comment: If you post the code that's in the form I will take a look.  Difficult to diagnose without that though.

Comment: Edit your question and add it there...

Comment: Got it!  I used ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Range.  Thanks Tim!